External disks not viisible via dock on 2019 MBP
I have two of each of these:

120v mains to USB-C power supply. They both exceed 85w.
USB-C to USB-C cable for power to dock.
dock.
USB-C to USB-C cable for dock to laptop.

I have my 2019 16" MBP and a brand new in package SanDisk USB-C thumb drive.
Here's the problem: I cannot see the thumb drive when it's plugged into the dock. diskutil activity shows nothing. No combination of cables, dock, and power shows any change in behavior. However, the thumb drive shows up in diskutil and mounts without issue if I plug it directly into the MBP.
My older external drives are also unable to mount via a dock. (My Time Machine drives becoming inaccessible were how I first noticed the problem.) However, they're all USB-A connectors, which the MBP doesn't match. I can find USB-C to USB-A adaptor, but I don't think it will reveal anything interesting.
My guess is that I have a low level configuration item set incorrectly. But, I have no idea what to really search for. What do I need to look at?
NB edit: I've already looked at

https://iboysoft.com/howto/how-to-find-usb-connected-devices-on-mac.html
External disk does not show in "diskutil list" after premature eject, what can I do?


Thumb to Mac works, thumb to dock fails. HDD to Mac may work, HDD to dock fails. Suggests problem is dock and/or the dock to Mac cable.  Try different port on Mac and then different dock and cable.  What make and model dock?

Is you dock to Mac USB-C cable a data cable (it might be power only)? Is the dock visible in Click Apple (top left), hold Option key and click on System Info - can you see the dock in tree for USB.
